# WCF Service Basic HTTP binding , SVC not accessible from outside server

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have hosted wcf service on one of our remote servers.

It is getting accessible on server when I click brows on IIS.

Eg. `http://10.42.420.420/ModuleName/ServiceName.svc`

But when I try to access it through my local desktop , on browser (having access on that remote server where I have hosted this WCF service) , It gives me error :- Site Can't Reach.

What can be the reason?

Note :- I have hosted it on Port :- 80

Only one service is there in IIS , no other services , so there is no question of other service using the same port.

Comment: Is Site working on local server where it is hosted? Try on server browser like http://localhost/ModuleName/ServiceName.svc

Comment: yes it is working on local server

Comment: If site is working & ping to server 10.42.420.420 from local machine is also ok, then only reason then can be firewall, proxy or some app restricting the connection. Otherwise it should work

Comment: When I ping , it gives me :- Pinging 10.42.420.420 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out. ,, but I am able to access this server through Remote Desktop Connection

Comment: That is main Issue here. Something is blocking access to your server. It can be firewall at server or antivirus/proxy server on you local. Resolve that, issue will be resolved. Remote connection is separate permission than browsing so remote is not equal to ping or http port 80 access